# Wait until ajax script is finished than show the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script that i used in my php page 
this is the script :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://www.exemple.com/jsonp?j=123",
            dataType: 'jsonp', // Notice! JSONP <-- P (lowercase)
            success:function(data){
                // I get data and i sendit to test
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'test/' + data,
                    type : 'POST',
                    complete: function(){
                        // the function test is complete
                    },
                });
            }},
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that my page shows just after the first ajax call, so i want it to be shown until the second ajax call takes effect !!!

Comment: how you are showing?  The respective code is not been included.

Comment: page shows after first ajax call?? in your first ajax success you are showing nothing but making another ajax call

Comment: The page shows no matter what call ajax is done or not, actually. You simply do nothing to prevent the page from showing. Got any plan for that? Either hide it in a div with display none or return the html in the second ajax call?

Comment: `}},` i can see a bad closing here.

Comment: use `spinner` to hide page, and show page when second call takes place

Answer (score 4):

Firstly place a `div` over the site, something like this:

```
<div id="overlay">
    Loading...
</div>
```

```css
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #FFF;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Then in the `complete` callback of the second AJAX call, remove that overlay once your UI has been set up.

```
complete: function(){
    // the function test is complete

    $("#overlay").fadeOut();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document.body).hide(); ///<--------hide it here
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://www.exemple.com/jsonp?j=123",
        dataType: 'jsonp', // Notice! JSONP <-- P (lowercase)
        success:function(data){
            // I get data and i sendit to test
            $.ajax({
                url: 'test/' + data,
                type : 'POST',
                complete: function(){
                    // the function test is complete
                   $(document.body).show(); ///<--------show it here
                }, // remove the traling comma here
            });
        } //<--------i see a bad closing here, remove the trailing comma
    });
});
```

---

Try hiding the `body` first, when your second ajax call gets completed you can show the `body`.

Comment: It's the same i prefer to show the body then do a reload than hide the body